# Do I need to install Apache Maven on my PC first, or is it enough to install the plugin in Netbeans to run a Maven project?

Tags: java, apache, maven, netbeans

I build an Apache Project in java which runs fine on my laptop, now that I try to run the same project in Netbeans on my work PC I get an error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project aping: Command execution failed.

With a reference to:

> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

The Maven plugin in Netbeans was installed by default. When I tried to find out if the Apache version in the POM file was correct I tried to check the version on my PC with `mvn -version` I got the error:

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Does this mean that Maven is not installed on my PC and should I also install Maven on my PC first in order to use the plugin, or should just installing the plugin be enough and do I have a different problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you see is

`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project aping: Command execution failed.`

This is a message from the Maven executable embedded inside Netbeans (so Maven *is* running), saying that a specific maven plugin (here exec-maven-plugin) failed.  This is most likely trying to invoke another program on your computer that is not installed so Netbeans (and hence the embedded Maven) can see it.

If you want to run maven outside Netbeans, you must download and install a copy and invoke the "mvn" binary inside.

Comment: Does that mean that I can run Maven within Netbeans without any additional installation?

Comment: Yes.  Netbeans brings it own copy of Maven.  And you are running Maven, otherwise you would not see this error message.

Comment: Since I just copied the and imported the zip file from my laptop, could this error have something to do with the references to versions etc. in the POM file?

Comment: Most likely not.  The error indicates that Maven tries to invoke a program which apparently is present on your laptop but not on your current computer.  Investigate to find out what that is.  If you cannot tell from the error messages around what you quoted, search for exec-maven-plugin in your pom and see what is expected to happen there?

Answer (score 0):

You Have to install Maven To run Maven on your PC - http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-maven-and-how-do-i-install-it.html see how to install maven

in linux - http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Note that the maven available in Ubuntu usually is not the newest.  For most cases this is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly assumed that the problem had something to do with Maven, the problem seems to be something in my source code unrelated to Maven. When I change some of the code the program is build succesfully

Comment: This might have to do with you transferring the project _along with_ the Netbeans project files.  They are not intended for being moved.